# Efficient way to store a fairly small amount of images in a single file in python?

Tags: python, animation, image-processing, file-management, storing-data

I'm a fairly novice programmer who is trying to create a simple 2d animation software for a school project. I want there to be the option to save a short animation as a single file so that it can be loaded by the program again. Part of this will be storing multiple images in a single file along with some metadata such as the frame number of the image and possibly its size and position on a canvas. I have done some research and have found multiple different methods which seem like they will work, but aren't really suited to this purpose. There's no documentation I can find online on how to build an animation software so I would really appreciate if someone could point me towards any suitable method I can use in python.

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider a GIF. You can read and write them in Python with PIL/Pillow, or Wand. You can see all the frames with **ImageMagick** using `magick animated.gif -coalesce frame-%3d.png` in the Terminal/Command Prompt.

Comment: The material here might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59078778/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own small file standard, where you set a specific length of bytes for your metadata for each image and a header that tells you how many images are stored in the file as well as their size. Then you could read that file by first reading the header (which has a specific length). This header then tells you how many images there are and their size. Then you always read a chunk of the file containing the metadata for each file (also a fixeed size in bytes) and then the image with a size in bytes that was given by the header. This is a bit of work to implement however.